# Couchbase operator 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 upgradation issue

Tags: couchbase

I am using couchbase server 5.5 with autonomous operator 1.1.0.
I made change in operator.yaml couchbase/operator:1.2.0.

But when I create cluster, all pods are coming up but cluster is always in provisioning state with following error:

```
time="2019-08-22T07:54:39Z" level=error msg="failed to reconcile: unable to create bucketName named - cb-bucket-1jzm9kr75: 
[Server Error 400 (cb-1jzm9jg2u-0000.cb-1jzm9jg2u.cb-1jzm9jg2u.svc:8091/pools/default/buckets): [compressionMode - compressionMode can be set to 'off', 'passive' or 'active']], 
[Server Error 400 (cb-1jzm9jg2u-0001.cb-1jzm9jg2u.cb-1jzm9jg2u.svc:8091/pools/default/buckets): [compressionMode - compressionMode can be set to 'off', 'passive' or 'active']], 
[Server Error 400 (cb-1jzm9jg2u-0002.cb-1jzm9jg2u.cb-1jzm9jg2u.svc:8091/pools/default/buckets): [compressionMode - compressionMode can be set to 'off', 'passive' or 'active']]" cluster-name=cb-1jzm9jg2u module=cluster
```

Comment: A new field was added to the buckets in 1.2

https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/1.2/couchbase-cluster-config.html#compressionmode
You will need to add this to the buckets in yout cluster definition
'passive' is the default